# Is this the normal curing process for my new driveway?

Tags: concrete, driveway

I had a concrete company come out and redo our driveway two days ago. I am wondering if the mottled pattern I see is a normal part of the drying process or if is there something going on.

I am also just wondering what the normal time is for parking on the driveway after the new one is put in because he said can’t park on it for 4 weeks which seems like a crazy long time to me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? The spots or something else?

Comment: Are the darker parts shadows, or is that what the problem is?

Comment: @RohitGupta there are spots on the concrete; the long dark areas are shadows—probably from the OP's legs.

Comment: What's your climate? How much rain do you expect in the next two weeks?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour], then respond to the questions above by adding information to your question post.

Comment: Not going to try to answer your question, but I do know that my reciprocating saw cut a nice clean slot in my concrete floor that had cured for about 10 days prior to my working on it. New concrete is quite soft for far longer than you might thing.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience, concrete is dry enough to touch within hours to a day.  It's normally hard enough to walk on after 24hrs, but it will scuff.  To reach full-rated strength, it can take a month.  So your contractor is correct because he does not want to redo it if you wreck it.

> **How Long Does Concrete Take to Dry**
> Concrete is usually dry enough after 24 to 48 hours to walk on. For concrete to dry and reach its full strength, it typically takes about 28 days per inch of slab thickness.
>
> Once conditions are conducive for the concrete to cure at 85-90% relative humidity. We say ‘once conditions are conducive’ because concrete put down a year ago might have been exposed to the elements for eleven months and only enclosed for the last month.

From [Wagnermeters](https://www.wagnermeters.com/concrete-moisture-test/concrete-info/how-to-speed-up-concrete-drying-time/)

> **HOW LONG DOES IT TAKE FOR CONCRETE TO CURE?**
> The entire curing period of concrete takes about a month, but your concrete will be ready for use sooner. Each project will vary slightly due to differences in the weather, concrete mix and placement and finishing techniques.
>
> When waiting for concrete to dry, keep these timeframes in mind:
>
> - 24 to 48 hours - after inital set, forms can be removed and people can walk on the surface
> - 7 days - after partial curing, traffic from vehicles and equipment is okay
> - 28 days - at this point, the concrete should be fully cured

From [concretenetwork](https://www.concretenetwork.com/curing-concrete/)

Comment: The 28 days to "fully cured" thing is somewhat false. It's a "shared wisdom" mantra that may or may not be accurate.  See https://precast.org/2013/10/28-day-myth

Answer (score 3):

The spots are part of the normal drying and curing process.

They will fade and the color will change over time.  It's normal.

Answer (score 2):

Concrete cures from the outside to the inside and the process can be relatively slow.

The strength develops over time so a 3" kitchen floor can be walked on after a day or so but drive that  may be 5" thick with the loading caused by a 3 ton vehicle supported by 4 tire footprints could easily damage "soft" concrete.

I did read somewhere that the concrete cast by the Romans 2000 years ago for the Coliseum is still curing in the centreb but that is a lot thicker than any drive...